# Rectangle in ZStack changing SwiftUI animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to transition between two states with SwiftUI.

I have reduced this to a simple example

```swift
struct Test2View: View {

    @State var isLoading: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color. secondary)
                .shadow(radius: 4, x: 2, y: 5)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 150, alignment: .center)

            if isLoading {
                Text("Loading")
                .transition(.moveAndFade())
            } else {
                Text("Content")
                .transition(.moveAndFade())
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                self.isLoading.toggle()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
extension AnyTransition {
    static func moveAndFade(delay: TimeInterval = 0) -> AnyTransition {
        let insertion = AnyTransition.offset(x: 0, y: 15)
            .combined(with: .opacity)
        let removal = AnyTransition.offset(x: 20, y: 20)
            .combined(with: .opacity)
        return .asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
    }
}
```

This works the way I expected without the RoundedRectangle:

[image]

However, as soon as I add the RoundRectangle I lose the removal animation (unless I interrupt the animation, then you can see the animation I was expecting):

[image]

Any idea why the RoundedRectangle messes with the animation? I even tried to add `.transition(.identity)` without any success.

Comment: Side note for anyone trying this code and can't see the text - it only works in light mode, not dark mode!

Comment: You are right, I have reduced this so much that I forgot about dark mode. Added foreground colors for dark mode. Thank you!

Comment: That's not how the dark mode should be done. The `Text` doesn't need a foreground modifier, because by default it will use the `primary` color. The problem is that your rectangle is white, which is the same color the text should be in dark mode. To fix this, on your original code replace `.fill(Color.white)` with `.fill(Color.secondary)`.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: It did help in that scenario, but as soon as I started to complicate it I had the same problem. I really would love to know what is happening under the hood, but I guess that will be hard to know . If I don't receive any answer in the next week I will approve yours. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell the exact reason why the animation changes, but I have found the cause. It's something to do with the size of the frame.

Your version of `Test2View`'s view body:

```
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .fill(Color.white)
        .shadow(radius: 4, x: 2, y: 5)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 150, alignment: .center)

    if isLoading {
        Text("Loading")
        .transition(.moveAndFade())
    } else {
        Text("Content")
        .transition(.moveAndFade())
    }
}
.border(Color.red)
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation {
        self.isLoading.toggle()
    }
}
```

Fixed version:

```
ZStack {
    if isLoading {
        Text("Loading")
        .transition(.moveAndFade())
    } else {
        Text("Content")
        .transition(.moveAndFade())
    }
}
.background(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .fill(Color.white)
        .shadow(radius: 4, x: 2, y: 5)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 150, alignment: .center)
)
.border(Color.green)
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation {
        self.isLoading.toggle()
    }
}
```

Basically, I used `.background` instead of creating a `VStack`.

Comparison images:

[image: Broken]
[image: Fixed]

<sup>*The border color is there just to indicate the frame size. You can remove this!*</sup>

Comment: It is oficial, I can't understand how SwiftUI does animations, here is another scenario: https://gist.github.com/tiagoalmeida/b64db4bc858d0342c5ce5b15a080b682 . Entering is not animated, but leaving it is.

Comment: (if you are wondering why I don't animate the VStack: - I want to add a delay to each part; - This is part of a larger VStack)